# CWnd::PreTranslateMessage - переопределение функции в DLL

Tags: c++, mfc

Как переопределить функцию `CWnd::PreTranslateMessage`в контексте `CWnd::SubclassWindow`?

```
bool Plugin::OnAppStartAfter(long CallParamBlock)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    SessionId = app->StartSessionFromCallParams(&CallParamBlock);
    if (SessionId != 0)
    {
        m_pWnd = CWnd::FindWindow(_T("#32770"), _T("MobiScript"));

        if (m_pWnd != NULL)
        {
            ACCEL m_accel[2];
            m_pMenu = m_pWnd->GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(0)->GetSubMenu(6);
            if (m_pMenu != NULL)
            {
                m_pMenu->InsertMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_EXPCATXML, _T("Catalog to XML\tCtrl+E"));
                m_accel[0].fVirt = FVIRTKEY | FCONTROL;
                m_accel[0].key = 0x45; // E
                m_accel[0].cmd = ID_EXPCATXML;
            }
            if (m_accel[0].cmd == ID_EXPCATXML)
            {
                plugin.m_hAccelTable = CreateAcceleratorTable(m_accel, 2);
            }
        }
        plugin.SubclassWindow(m_pWnd->m_hWnd);
        plugin.PreTranslateMessage(AfxGetCurrentMessage());
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}
BOOL Plugin::PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg)
{
    if (plugin.m_hAccelTable)
    {
        if (::TranslateAccelerator(m_pWnd->m_hWnd, plugin.m_hAccelTable, pMsg))
        {
            return(TRUE);
        }
    }
    return CWnd::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Необходимо как-то транслировать таблицу акселераторов в контексте переопределения оконной процедуры 'MobiScript'. С точки зрения стандартного приложения MFC, функция `PreTranslateMessage` выполняется с момента загрузки приложения в память. В моем случае, приходится инициализировать функцию `PreTranslateMessage` в теле функции `OnAppStartAfter`. Пожалуйста, поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.
Спасибо

Comment: Даже MS признала MFC мертвым несколько лет тому назад. Посмотрите на более удобные средства.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я не возражаю от использования традиционного WinAPI, просто не могу найти решение в контексте данного приложения. Например, попытка переопределить оконную процедуру на базе приложения Win32 не дало положительных результатов. Напротив, функция `CWnd::SubclassWindow` из библиотеки MFC, работает. То что MS признал MFC мертвым, это заблуждение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы в вашем плагине работала (вообще вызывалась) функция `PreTranslateMessage`, вам нужно внедриться в 
основной цикл сообщений главной программы.

**Первый способ.** Чтобы `PreTranslateMessage` вызывалась, нужно создавать MFC Extension DLL.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будет работать **только если** основное приложение тоже использует MFC Shared Library.

**Второй способ.** Этого можно добиться даже в MFC Regular DLL, если есть возможность изменить код основной программы (не ваш случай):

Цитата из MSDN:

> If the DLL opens modeless dialogs or has a main frame window of its
>   own, the application's main message pump must call a routine exported
>   by the DLL, which in turn calls the CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage
>   member function of the DLL's application object.

Т.е. вы должны создать и экспортировать в DLL некую функцию

```
extern "C" BOOL PASCAL __declspec(dllexport) DllPreTranslateMessage (MSG * pMsg) 
{ 
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE (AfxGetStaticModuleState ()); 
    return theApp.PreTranslateMessage (PMSG); 
}
```

а потом вызывать ее из основной программы:

```
BOOL CMyApp::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{ 
    if (DllPreTranslateMessage (pMsg)) 
        return TRUE; 
    return CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg); 
}
```

Однако у вас нет доступа к коду основной программы.

**Третий способ.** Можно установить хук (скажем, на `WH_GETMESSAGE`) и отлавливать нужные сообщения вручную.

Comment: 1. Маловероятно, что будет работать; 3. Не понятно, что Вы имели ввиду. Вы предлагаете обходной путь реализации `TranslateAccelerator`?

Comment: @ViteDecorum
>Вы предлагаете обходной путь реализации TranslateAccelerator? 
обходной путь реализации `PreTranslateMessage`

Comment: @ViteDecorum Но у вас и выбора-то особо нет, если только случайно в SDK не найдете функцию, добавляющую accelerator. Вам действительно так необходимо заморачиваться с вложенным меню?

Comment: В целом, задача вставки меню решена. Но мне интересно, что получится с таблицей акселераторов. Я понимаю, данный вопрос не совсем относится к традиционному программированию, но тем не менее. Полезная статья [Meandering Through the Maze of MFC Message and Command Routing](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0795/dilascia/dilascia.aspx)

Comment: Вариант (3) работает, но только через сопоставление `wParam`. Подскажите, как сопоставить комбинацию `Ctrl+E`?

Comment: @ViteDecorum `if ( wParam == _T('E') && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x80 ) { `

Comment: возможно транслировать акселераторы, используя функцию `SetWindowsHookEx`?

Answer (score 0):

@zenden2k, Вы были правы, вариант (3) работает:

```
bool Plugin::OnAppStartAfter(long CallParamBlock)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    SessionId = app->StartSessionFromCallParams(&CallParamBlock);
    if (SessionId != 0)
    {
        m_pWnd = CWnd::FindWindow(_T("#32770"), _T("MobiScript"));

        if (m_pWnd != NULL)
        {
            m_pMenu = m_pWnd->GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(0)->GetSubMenu(6);
            if (m_pMenu != NULL)
            {
                m_pMenu->InsertMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_EXPCATXML, _T("Catalog to XML"));
            }
            m_pMenu = m_pWnd->GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(0)->GetSubMenu(7);
            if (m_pMenu != NULL)
            {
                m_pMenu->InsertMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_IMPCATXML, _T("Catalog to XML"));
            }
        }
        plugin.SubclassWindow(m_pWnd->m_hWnd);
        hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, hMod, 0);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0 || nCode != HC_ACTION)
        return CallNextHookEx(hhook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0 && wParam == 0x45 && GetActiveWindow() == m_pWnd->m_hWnd)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(L"Ctrl+E");
        return 1;
    }
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0 && wParam == 0x49 && GetActiveWindow() == m_pWnd->m_hWnd)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(L"Ctrl+I");
        return 1;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hhook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Единственный момент, который меня волнует, это оптимизация. Хотел решить данный вопрос на базе MFC, но по-видимому нет вариантов.